# How to send Text to end of the screen in react-native

Tags: react-native

*I want to send `<Text> World </Text>` end of the screen.*

**This is my code :**

```
  <Text style={{position: 'relative}}>
     <Text>Hello</Text>    <Text style={{position: 'absolute', right:0}>World</Text> 
  </Text>
```

I guess `right: 0`  sends 'world' end of the in this text `<Text style={{position: 'absolute', right:0}>World</Text>`. How do I send child `<Text>` end of   parent `<Text>` ?

**Edited :**

```
 <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>         <Text>World</Text> 
        </Text>  
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
     <Text>Hello</Text>    
     <Text>World</Text> 
 </View>
```

**EDIT**
This should work, you don't need a parent `<Text>`. This `TouchableOpacity` will act if you click both text's

```
<TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
       <Text>Hello</Text>         
       <Text>World</Text> 
    </View>  
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I can not put View because it is  in TouchableOpacity. I edited my post bro

Comment: Do you want the `TouchableOpacity` to be in both texts? or do you want one to each text?

Comment: I want to give Text to TouchableOpacity. And Text has two word so I want to sen 1 of word end of the Text. and other one beggining of Text.

Comment: I tried that before, but it gives me an error like :  "Text strings mustbe rebdered withing a Text component"

Comment: oh, that's probably because you have a space between components and that's why you can't see them, try to delete every space between components

Comment: Oh man thx so so much I would be able to find never ever  that mistake. It solved my problem !